# Uploading Files to Server with jcifs - jcifs.smb.SmbException: Broken pipe

Tags: android, jcifs

I'm uploading images and videos from an android application to a server with smb. I'm using jcifs. For some times all works good. After few days the aplication don't upload files and I receive the following error:

```
jcifs.smb.SmbException: Broken pipe
java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe
```

After reboot the phone all files uploaded and all works fine. But after a few days the error is back and I must restart the phone.

This is the place where the error occurs:

```
NtlmPasswordAuthentication auth = new NtlmPasswordAuthentication("",SMBUser, SMBPassword);
SmbFile smbFile = new SmbFile(path,auth);
```

This is my code for upload files:

```
 FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fileSource);
                    SmbFileOutputStream smbfos = new SmbFileOutputStream(smbFile2);
// writing data
                    try {
                        // 16 kb
                        final byte[] b  = new byte[16*1024];
                        int read = 0;
                        while ((read=fis.read(b, 0, b.length)) > 0) {
                            smbfos.write(b, 0, read);
                        }
                    }
```

Is there a way to resolve this problem?

THANKS!!!

Comment: smbfos.close(); ?

Comment: No. That is not the problem. I have smbfos.close in the code :-(